# Make a IPC call to COM object?

Tags: c#, com, arcgis

I have a plugin based application developing with ESRI ArcGIS Engine in C#.I have to rewrite it to a out of process plugin architecture because of 2/3G virtual memory limitation of 32-bit operating system(WindowsXP). In old source code almost every plugin call MapControl object(a COM object in ESRI ArcGIS Engine software) directly. There are too much work while wrapper MapControl and its related objects as remoting objects.

The question is, is there a way to make inter-process call to MapControl COM object so i dont bother to do a lot of wrappers?

While developing in C#, there are bridges called CCW(COM Callable Wrapper) between .Net object and COM object to intermediate comminications. Does it work intercepting CCW object and make it a remoting object?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can intercept the CCW the way you suggest.

Can't you configure the COM component as a local server with a DLL surrogate?